# Package instance variables in rails controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm overwhelmed by managing instance variables in controllers so am thinking if there's a better way to manage them.

My situation is, I'm having a `PagesController` that handles the front page rendering. In the front page, I have multiple small forms that originally belong to different controllers (For example, make a new post form, and there's a PostsController dedicated for it but for convenience you can make an easy post just at the front page.) and they all need their corresponding instance variable to hold the form (e.g. new post form needs a @post object).

It turns out to me, that I have to manually add these instance variables into my `PagesController#index` in order to make the forms work, so many lines become just

```
@post = Post.new # similar for other objects
@some_other_var = OtherController.new # another one
@one_more = AnotherController.new # again
# even more @variables here when the website is big
```

If this doesn't seem bad enough, think about when `create` or `edit` action fails (e.g. does not pass validation) and we need to render the previous page. We need to add these lines AGAIN. Actually we need to include ALL THESE VARIABLES whenever there's a render.

It seems very cumbersome to manually type such code to every action that needs them and it's so easy to just miss one or two of them when the website gets complicated.

So I'm wondering if there's a better way to manage such variables so that we only need to include them once instead of writing the same code every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `before_filter` something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  ...
  protected

    def instance_variables_for_form
      @post = Post.new # similar for other objects
      @some_other_var = OtherController.new # another one
      @one_more = AnotherController.new # again
      # even more @variables here when the website is big
    end

  end
```

and use it like:

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :instance_variables_for_form, only: [:action]
    ...
    ...
  end
```

and then you can call it explicitly too from any action whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

If those variables can be logically grouped, you should consider putting them into Presenter objects.

Here is a good blog post explaining the idea: http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html